# rails hidden fields and or sql database relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an autocomplete field for a users zip code. The autocomplete pulls from the `zip_codes` table (which also contains lat and long for each zip code).

However, I want it to save the users lat and long coordinates in the background when they submit the form. Is there a database relationship I can set up or something in my model to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about so?:

in your model:

```
before_save :populate_lat_and_long, :if => :changing_zipcode?

...
private

def changing_zipcode?
  self.zipcode_changed?
end

def populate_lat_and_long
  entry = ZipCode.where(:zipcode => self.zipcode).first
  self.lat, self.long = entry.lat, entry.long
end
```

/Removed plural from zipcodes

Answer (score 0):

If your form is set up to send only the zip code through your params hash, why don't you do a lookup on that zip in your controller, and then do your model.save. There's nothing that says you can't modify your model object manually in the controller before you call your save function.

Or if you're following the thin controllers, thick models paradigm, this code would go in your model. You should probably override your attribute accessors for user.zip to automatically populate user.lat and user.long.

Comment: any way you can give me a quick tidbit of model code on how to save an attribute? :) Thanks so much for your help!